# AWS EC2 can not access ' /bin/bash: Permission denied'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, centos

I have followed the tutorial here to shrink the size of EBS volume: [Shrinking CentOS 7 EBS boot volume on AWS](https://www.raygibson.net/2017/06/30/shrinking-centos-7-ebs-boot-volume-on-aws/)

Everything works fine but when I attached the smaller volume to the instance, it passed the health checks but I can not get in the server by SSH. I have received the error saying:

```
/bin/bash: Permission denied
Connection to xxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com closed.
```

I took an instance screenshot (Centos 7 on AWS), it only shows:

```
ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx login:
```

I checked ssh xxx -v. Here is what I found. You can see the authentication is good but it seems to be some permission issue.

```
OpenSSH_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/hbin/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/xxx/.ssh/config line 51: Applying options for testoc
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xxxxxxxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/xxx/.ssh/bin.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/xxx/.ssh/bin.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to xxxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:22 as 'centos'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:uH7uGEBzA8Xb7spU09lMX+YwHeIOzUNgau73aWVMuJQ
debug1: Host 'xxxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts:61
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/xxx/.ssh/bin.pem
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to xxxxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com ([xx.xxx.xx.xxx]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
Last login: Fri Oct 26 05:22:27 2018 from xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
/bin/bash: Permission denied
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to xxxxxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com closed.
Transferred: sent 2688, received 2520 bytes, in 0.3 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 8139.0, received 7630.3
debug1: Exit status 1
```

**Edited:**
This is what I found in the /var/log/messages

```
audit event#012node=ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.ec2.internal type=AVC msg=audit(1540551433.206:1290): avc:  denied  { dyntransition } for  pid=2525 comm="sshd" scontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:sshd_net_t:s0 tclass=process#012#012node=ip-172-31-94-158.ec2.internal type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1540551433.206:1290): arch=c000003e syscall=1 success=no exit=-13 a0=6 a1=56221eba6780 a2=20 a3=7ffcffca72a0 items=0 ppid=2524 pid=2525 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="sshd" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 key=(null)
```

Comment: Attach and mount that volume on another (working) machine so you can examine the syslogs for possible clues.  It looks like you are logging in successfully and then encountering an error, which closes the connection.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks. I check the /var/log/messages. I found some "denied" messages. I added to the question. Do you have any suggestion on it?

Comment: I'm getting the exact same error. It may go away after I leave the server up for a while, but I don't see why. Did you ever get an answer?

Comment: @A.L.Flanagan The problem was solve at that time. I was looking at my note. I have attached below and hope it can help. I was doing it for my cloud storage system (owncloud) so you may not need to do all of them.

Comment: 1. Create an AMI and snapshot from the owncloud instance
2. Create a volume from snapshot in the same region
3. Create a smaller volume in the same region
4. Follow this tutorial but don't use the way it migrate the data: https://www.raygibson.net/2017/06/30/shrinking-centos-7-ebs-boot-volume-on-aws/
5. rsync -avxPAHX --xattrs /mnt/xvdf1/ /mnt/xvdg1/
6. Follow the way in this article to change UUID and install the grub

Comment: 7. Detach and attach to the previous instance and start
8. Get to the owncloud folder to change the config.php
9. Configure the firewall:
# firewall-cmd --add-service http --permanent
# firewall-cmd --add-service https --permanent
# firewall-cmd --reload

Comment: Thanks much for the notes, I'm keeping them for reference. My problem turned out to be a different cause.